# how to do postback Javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="if(confirm_delete()){
/* post back*/
}else{
return false;
};" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" Text="delete"/>
```

Hi I have this code but I cant do postback for it, im not sure how to?

is it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function CallServer() {
            __doPostBack('not sure what goes here','or here');
        }  
</script>
```

Then:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="if(confirm_delete()){
/CallServer()/
}else{
return false;
};" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" Text="delete"/>
```

My other script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

On the server side i dynamically add a div to my page with content from my database for each content there is a new div will be added, each div is then refrenced with idWallPosting (so i can call my delete function)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.IO;

public partial class UserProfileWall : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btn.Visible = false;
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
    private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
    {

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            {
                //("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    test1.Controls.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.Attributes["class"] = "test";


                        div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        // this line is responsible, problem here and my sqlsntax, im trying to set the SELECT idWallPosting for the div ID
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));

                        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;" + "{0}", reader.GetString(1))));
                        div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

                        div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                        test1.Controls.Add(div);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{

    //    string id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_26";
    //    string[] idFragments = id.Split('_');
    //    id = idFragments[idFragments.Length - 1];

    //    //serverside code if confirm was pressed.
    //        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
    //        {
    //            cn.Open();
    //            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM WallPosting WHERE idWallPosting = " + id + ")", cn))
    //            {
    //                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //            }
    //        }
    //        //PopulateWallPosts();

    //}

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_26";
        string[] idFragments = id.Split('_');
        id = idFragments[idFragments.Length - 1];

        //serverside code if confirm was pressed.
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM WallPosting WHERE idWallPosting = " + id + ")", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //PopulateWallPosts();
    }
}
```

On my asp.net html side i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
</script>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();" runat="server" 
        CssClass="Btn" Text="delete" onclick="btn_Click"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="3" 
        Height="47px" Width="638px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post Message" Width="98px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </p>
<p>
</p>
    <style type="text/css">
    img {border-width:0px; width:100px; height:100px;}
</style>
    <div id="test1" runat="server" />

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

If you notice in my server side code I added this line:

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();")
```

This works any time I click on my div the `confirm_delete` is called.

What I was trying to do with my asp.net button was when the div was clicked I could then call the `onclick btnDelete_click`.

Comment: The code `if (xyz == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` seems a little redundant. Wouldn't `return xyz;` be cleaner and less error-prone?

Comment: Garrith: show us the complete aspx context. Are you using UpdatePanels? Does it work if you simply write `OnClientClick="javascript: return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?");"`?

Comment: updated hope ive explain'd it better

Comment: I'n not sure why the handler is not called - first i thought it was because you are clearing the controls of the DIV on every postback, but the button is not part of it. But if you only want to call its handler you could set it's style display to `none` and call __doPostBack(see my answer) to call the Button-handler from the div's click event(after confirmation).

Comment: Don't add the onclick handler as an attribute. Use `OnClick` and `OnClientClick` in the aspx file. The server will wrap those handlers and set the `onclick` for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();"
```

That's it...

Edit: __doPostBack works also...

```
OnClientClick="if(confirm('delete?'))__doPostBack('btn',''); else return false;"
```

Comment: already tryed that man, it wont call server side code, if i manually hit the button the code is called but trying it with javascript nothing happens

Comment: @Garrith, that's the point though isn't it? If you don't want it to delete, there's no reason to hit the server.

Comment: @Garrith: this works in most browsers(i'm not sure with IE<7). What Browser have you tested and have you browser-addins installed?

Answer (score 4):

If you really are wanting to manually call `__doPostBack()`, the first parameter is the .NET generated name for the control. This can be gotten on the server side using `Control.ClientID`. The second parameter is any extra data that should be passed along in the request. Most of the time I see this field is an empty string.

```
__doPostBack('ctl100$controlName$id','');
```

The `controlName` is the .NET class name of the control I believe, `id` is the ID you gave the control. To be sure, view the source of the page after it has been rendered in the browser and search for calls to `__doPostBack` and see how they are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

By a postback in this case do you want to just refresh the page? If so then it would just be:

```
    location.reload();
```

in your case:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallServer() 
        {
               location.reload();
        }
    </script>
```

**Demo** *(A button click prompts the user to confirm - if they choose Yes, a post back occurs)*

[See demo here!](http://jsfiddle.net/jtEvG/)

Comment: by postback i mean the button onclick (not client onlick) isnt calling server side code?

Comment: If Tim's solution didn't work for you - perhaps there is a conflict between the OnClientClick and OnClick methods. Try removing one of them to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: if i remove onclickclient i cant call the javascript, if i delete the onclick then i cant call the server side code so how does that help?

Comment: If all you are doing is using the Javascript for a confirmation - then Tim's solution should work for you. I was suggesting that to determine if perhaps syntax was an issue with one or both of your onClientClick / onClick statements.

Comment: hey Rion I think i was slightly wrong in what i ment i was trying to do, i have a div which fires my javascript i was trying to bind my asp button to the call so when i clicked on the div and was asked for confirmation it would fire the asp onClick event in the code behind

Answer (score 1):

One method, not the best for sure:
Add a button into an update panel and set it invisble.
Then call click() method of the button.

Somthing like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').click();
```